# displaying selected value from popup after form submit if error comes

Tags: php, html

I have one text-box when user click on it one popup window gets open which contains many radio options ,when user selects any one of them and click on submit button on form ,than value comes in that text-box ,but when user click on submit button and if error comes on form than that text-box value vanishes ,how can i restore it ? 
this the text-box code

```
<input  title="Enter Kind of work 1" 
        readonly="readonly"  
        onclick="if(this.value!=''){this.value='';opendrop();}else{opendrop();}" 
        id="other_work1" 
        name="other_work1" 
        type="text" 
        size="20" 
        maxlength="20"  
        onclick='opendrop()'
        <?php if (isset($errors)) { 
                  echo 'value="'.htmlentities(@$_POST['other_work1']).'"'; 
              } 
        ?>
>
```

this is function i am calling

```
function opendrop()
{
var popy= window.open('kind.php','popup_form','width=380 height=300 left=800 top=300');
}
```

Comment: show full html code please. Make print_r($_POST) - what do you see?

Comment: shall i show `kind.php` also?

Comment: your HTML and PHP code please.